# Basic web application but getting 404 error Tomcat/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a simple dynamic web application in eclipse as shown in below image:

[image]

and my web.xml is as below (provided only relavent sections to reduce complexity):

```
<web-app ... 
<display-name>DemoRest</display-name>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>JerseyWebService</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JerseyWebService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But when I run I am getting "404 error" as shown below:
[image]

As you can see my Context-Path matches with my folder and actual files are there in correct location, still I am not able to run the application. I tried of cleaning, rebuilding, restarting of eclipse but still no luck. Can anyone help me, why this happens with tomcat?

Comment: upload your jsp source code.

Comment: Its just a basic code, with nothing on it I have only <h1> test </h1> with it.

Comment: see my answer and try this..remove your code and put mine it ll works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>JerseyWebService</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is not available because the url

```
 http://localhost:8080/DemoRest/NewFile.jsp
```

will be intercepted by JerseyWebService, which I guess is not an intended action.

Why not host rest services on path like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>JerseyWebService</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```